# Is it possible to make flash drive to boot Virtual Box with Windows machines like live CD

Tags: linux, virtualbox, liveusb

Is it possible to make bootable Linux live flash drive to boot directly Virtual Box with Windows Machine without Linux desktop and unnecessary libraries and packages? Any ready-to-use solutions? (noob question)

Comment: No. Well unless of course you don’t have to directly interact with the VM.

Comment: Without a Linux? No

Comment: Dunno if this will be applicable for you: HirenBootCD has what they call MiniXP. It's an XP hack. On it you can run Windows applications. It won't be able to run everything, as it's not the full OS, and is without any service pack. I keep it on my thumbs drive, amongst other useful utilities on the go

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should indeed be possible. Here's a rough idea-

-Install Linux(Ubuntu?) on a flash drive. Boot into it.

-Set up VirtualBox and make a script that will boot Windows. Check the command-line options in the documentation for how to do this.

-Make a file with the .desktop extension in `usr/share/xsessions`.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/path/to/your/script
Name=Windows
Comment=Testing
```

This should add "Windows" in the list of desktop environments on the login screen. [Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/310671/start-ubuntu-without-a-desktop-environment-but-start-an-x-application)

-Uninstall any unnecessary packages, I.E the desktop environment and such. You can always switch to a console with ctrl+alt+f1 and re-install them.

-Log out and choose "Windows" as your desktop environment

-Hope that nothing explodes

(Note: hopefully, if you choose "log in automatically" when installing linux, the machine will go directly to your VM when booting without asking for a login. Also- this should work with Ubuntu, but I don't know about other distributions)

Comment: Anton Liakhovitch, you are super-hero, thank you!